# What is causing my console crash?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, memory, garbage

I'm having problems with a bit of code I've written that cycles through an array of ads. 
The render function gets called on an interval (configurable, but set to every 50ms to help with debugging). The problem is, when this function runs too many times, the console crashes. On some mobile phones, the device will run out of memory completely and restart itself, and I think it's related to this function (console doesn't crash if I take it out):

```
var render = function(){
    if(ads.length < 1)
        return;
    if(!ads[adIndex]){
        adIndex = 0;
    }
    s = ads[adIndex].src;
    w = ads[adIndex].width;
    $(adContainer).html("<p>ADVERTISEMENT</p><img src = '" + s + "' width = '" + w + "'/>");
    adIndex++;
};
```

I'm thinking it might be a memory leak, but I'm not a memory expert by any means.  Is there something I can do to optimize this function and prevent memory issues?

Edit: I'm calling the code like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
        render();
    }, 50);
```

And the ads array is simply an array of javascript Image() objects.

Comment: Not enough code to tell. how do you call render?

Comment: setInterval(function(){
            render();
        }, 50);

Can't really post all the code, it's a really complex site I've been working on for months.

Comment: you may want to show the ads object. And update your question with the code, dont paste as a comment

Comment: `setInterval(render, 50);` Will give you the same result without useless wrapping function.

Comment: I don't think the reason for the crash is here. What made you think it is here?

Comment: Because if I comment out everything within the render function, it doesn't crash.

Comment: Try increasing the interval, 50ms in way too fast anyway!

Comment: Like I said in the original post, the 50ms interval is just to speed up the crash for debugging purposes. Usually it's configured to run every 5 seconds, but crashes after a long period of use.

Comment: What exactly is the "console" you're referring too? Is this just a normal HTML web page being displayed in a browser, or is it something more specialised like a Windows Store app?

Comment: How many images are contained in your ads array?

Comment: The console is the web console. This is a webpage.

The ads array right now just contains two ads and cycles through them.

Comment: How many images and how big are these images?

Comment: There are two and they are small (~300px on a side).

Comment: There is too little code here. Can you make a jsfiddle reproduction?

Answer (score 0):

I just think the problem is below code.

```
$(adContainer)
```

You created JQuery Object everytime.

```
var $adContainer = $(adContainer);
var render = function(){
    if(ads.length < 1)
        return;
    if(!ads[adIndex]){
        adIndex = 0;
    }
    s = ads[adIndex].src;
    w = ads[adIndex].width;
    $adContainer.html("<p>ADVERTISEMENT</p><img src = '" + s + "' width = '" + w + "'/>");
    adIndex++;
};
```

And then I recommend to use setTimeout like this looping case